# js область видимости

Tags: javascript, scope

Доброго времени суток.

Как можно обратиться к `name` объекта `t` и можно ли вообще ?

```
var t = {
name:123,
fio: () => {
    console.log(this.name)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В случае использования стрелочной функции для метода - только через переменную `t`, так как внутри такой функции - контекст тот же, что и в месте ее объявления. Вызов `console.log(this.name);` выводит в консоль `window.name`.

```js
var t = {
  name:123,
  fio: () => {
    console.log("this.name = " + this.name)
    console.log("t.name = " + t.name)
  }
}

t.fio();
console.log(t.name);
console.log(window.name);
```

С обычной функцией, `this` - объект, на котором происходит ее вызов.

```js
var t = {
  name:123,
  fio: function() {
    console.log("in fio = " + this.name)
  },
  fio1() {
    console.log("in fio1 = " + this.name); 
  }
}

t.fio1();
t.fio();
console.log(t.name);
console.log(window.name);
```

Comment: Ещё метод покажи: `fio() {`